# Wordpress upgrade to 4.4.2 failed

Tags: wordpress

My setup:

```
OS: CentOS 7.1
http user: apache
http group: apache
```

When i perform automatic update, I get below error:

> Downloading update from
>   https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.4.2-new-bundled.zip…
>
> Unpacking the update…
>
> The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy
>   some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.:
>   wp-admin/includes/update-core.php
>
> Installation Failed

I have tried upgrade with full permission but no luck:

```
#find . -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
#find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Anyone has any clues?  I searched for hours but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up upgrading manually which worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

**Do Not** use `777` permission! Wordpress only need `755` for directories, `644` for files, and `666` for `themes` and `plugins` directories & files. And you could give `600` to `wp-config.php` for security. You can see Wordpress documentation for [file permission](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

I had this problem, and this is how I solved the issues.

- Make sure all owned by Apache.
  `sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/sitedir`
- Give proper permissions
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`
  that would give `755` permission to all directory inside `sitedir`
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +`
  that would give `644` to all files
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir/wp-content/themes -type f -exec chmod 666 {} +`
  `sudo find /var/www/html/sitedir/wp-content/plugins -type f -exec chmod 666 {} +`
  those two commands above make `666` permission to all files inside themes and plugins directory
- If you use selinux 

  `sudo chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/sitedir`
  `sudo chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/sitedir/wp-content`
  Two commands above would change the context of your files and directories. And restart php-fpm if you use one.
  **UPDATE:**
  If you don't get through until this point. You might also need to set a local policy module for selinux.
  `sudo grep php-fpm /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol`
  `sudo semodule -i mypol.pp`
  Then restart php-fpm.

I also [cover this Wordpress permission issue](http://www.unixius.com/fail-wordpress-update-plugins-permission-centos/) more detail on my blog :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some (security) plugins seem to interfere with updating older versions of WordPress. Try deactivating plugins and trying again.

If all else fails, just perform a manual update via FTP.

Comment: But one comment worth mentioning is that I copied the entire site and setup locally using xampp on win7.  There the upgrade went smooth.  That's why I never doubted the plugins.